# What is this NSErrorPointer type?

Tags: pointers, swift, ampersand

1. In Swift the ampersand sign `&` is for `inout` parameters. Like

   > var value = 3
   >
   > func inoutfunc(inout onlyPara: Int) {
   >
   > onlyPara++
   >
   > }
   >
   > inoutfunc(&value) // value is now 4

   That doesn't look like `onlyPara` is a pointer, maybe it is and get dereferences immediately when using it inside the function.
   **Is onlyPara a pointer?**
2. When I don't need a `IntPointer` type, **why are the framework methods using a `NSErrorPointer` type?** Because they can't change the methods because of existing Objective-C code?
3. But **why is then Swift converting `&error` to `NSErrorPointer`**, is that autoboxed?

   > var errorPtr: NSErrorPointer = &error
4. And when I have a `NSErrorPointer`. **How do I dereference it?**

   > var error: NSError = *errorPtr // won't work

---

Maybe someone can enlighten me. Using only Swift is easy. I think the questions are one chunk of knowledge over `&` between swift and Objective-C (as the address of operator)

Comment: Have you read [In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) from *Swift Programming Language*?

Comment: Yes in swift only (there no NSErrorPointer would be needed right?) it is easy, but that doesn't say anything (e.g. 3.:) why a NSError automatically is a NSErrorPointer, when using `&`, etc.

Comment: NSErrorPointer and its usage is described in "Error Reporting" in the "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" book: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you read the Pointers section of the Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_16

There is a table at the bottom of the Pointers section, which explains how class pointers bridge to Swift pointer types. Based on that, the NSError pointer should be `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError>`. Searching trough the headers for NSErrorPointer yields this:

```
typealias NSErrorPointer = AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?>
```

Why the extra `?` after `NSError`? I guess it's because NSError can also be `nil`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: But how does a NSError with an ampersand automatically convert to NSErrorPointer? Does `&` mean address of? I didn't read that in Swift.

Comment: There are no actual pointers in Swift. Everything is an object. & basically means:
`Create an object of type AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<Type>, where Type is the type of the object referenced by the & operator.`
The resulting object contains the type and actual pointers to the memory of the object that you're referencing. You do not have direct access to the pointer, but instead they give you a nice object to work with.

Comment: That was a very good explanation. So the `inout` keyword creates this `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer` but let the work with the actual object `NSError` inside the `func` instead of the argument (`& NSError`) given. That is very clever. I love Swift more and more.

Comment: Glad it made sense!

One more thing; `inout` doesn't actually create anything. It's just a keyword that tells the compiler that the function which specifies `inout` for an argument only accepts an `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer` of that argument.

Answer (score 7):

Solution to 4. I found out how to dereference it:

```
var error: NSError = errorPtr.memory!
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3

```
var errorPtr: NSErrorPointer = nil
callSomeFunctionThatReceivesParamByReference(.., error: errorPtr)
if let error = errorPtr?.pointee { ... }
```

Comment: Is it ok to not add "?" behind NSErrorPointer ?